# Run task only if host does not belong to a group

Tags: ansible

I'd like to able to run an ansible task only if the host of the current playbook **does not belong** to a certain group. In semi pseudo code:

```
- name: my command
  command: echo stuff
  when: "if {{ ansible_hostname }} not in {{ ansible_current_groups }}"
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 258, accepted):

Here's another way to do this:

```
- name: my command
  command: echo stuff
  when: "'groupname' not in group_names"
```

`group_names` is a magic variable as documented here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html :

> group_names is a list (array) of all the groups the current host is in.

Comment: +1 and if you don't include the surrounding quote you get the error: `This one looks easy to fix.  It seems that there is a value started
with a quote, and the YAML parser is expecting to see the line ended
with the same kind of quote.`

Comment: I find this approach more readable and convenient to write, but both work equally well. `when: inventory_hostname not in groups.certain_groups`

Comment: This way is more robust than `inventory_hostname in groups['groupname']` because in cases where the grout itself does not exist, Ansible will throw an error like "Make sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-': argument of type 'StrictUndefined' is not iterable"

Comment: The link now should be https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables. The doc has been moved around.

Comment: I dont understand if `<list of groups the current host is part of>` then why would someone put a `if my current host not in my current groups execute command` which will never execute in their tasks?

Answer (score 26):

You can set a control variable in vars files located in `group_vars/` or directly in hosts file like this:

```
[vagrant:vars]
test_var=true

[location-1]
192.168.33.10 hostname=apollo

[location-2]
192.168.33.20 hostname=zeus

[vagrant:children]
location-1
location-2
```

And run tasks like this:

```
- name: "test"
  command: "echo {{test_var}}"
  when: test_var is defined and test_var
```

Comment: accepted answer is more accurate for the question, but this leads you down a better path

Answer (score 6):

I have came up with this:

```
- name: my command
  command: echo stuff
  when: inventory_hostname not in groups.get('your-group', [])
```