# Ansible: Run task if server belongs to a group

Tags: ansible

What's the sane way run a task only if the host belongs to one or more groups?

Currently, I'm using a boolean within the relevant group, e.g.:

### Inventory file

```
[db_servers:vars]
copy_connection_string=true
```

### Task

```
-
  name: Copy db connection string file
  synchronize: src= ... (truncated for clarity)
  when: copy_connection_string is defined
```

What's the right condition in the `when` clause to check whether the current host belongs to the `db_servers` group?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run task only if host does not belong to a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008083/run-task-only-if-host-does-not-belong-to-a-group)

Comment: I wouldn't say so. That's a similar question but it's not the same question.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

#### Run task when a host server is a member of a specific group

Ansible contains [special or magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables) - [one of the most common is `group_names` which is a list (array) of all the groups the current host is in.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables)

```
- name: Copy db connection string file
  synchronize:.........
  when: "'db_servers' in group_names"
```

The above Ansible task will only run if the host is a member of the `db_servers` group.