# Ansible - How to run tasks on specific host only and not on all 'inventory_hosts'?

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I have 3 applications hosted on three separate hosts and mentioned in the `my.hosts` file like below:

```ini
[app1_webapp]
host3.mybank.com

[app2_webapp]
host5.mybank.com

[app3_webapp]
host8.mybank.com
```

My requirement is to run two types of `raw` module commands.

1. First `raw` task which should run on all three hosts for all three applications, i.e `uptime`
2. Second `raw` task is `ps` command that should run only on the respective  host, i.e `ps -ef | grep app1` should only run on `host3.mybank.com`

Below is how I call

```bash
ansible-playbook -i my.hosts main.yml -e appname=app1,app2,app3
```

and my `main.yml`

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ product(appname.split(',')) | product(['webapp'])|map('flatten')|map('join', '_') }}"

  user: user1
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

    - name: Check Running Process
      raw: "ps -ef | grep {{ item }}"
      register: psout
      with_items: "{{ appname.split(',') }}"

    - name: DUMP Running Process
      debug: 
        msg: "{{ psout.stdout }}"
```

The above `raw` fails as it tried `ps` for each app on each hosts which is what I wish to skip (correct).

How do I put a when condition so that the `ps` command for the respective app should run on the respective host only and not on all three hosts?

Comment: I would say you are facing a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info), where you want us to solve your trial at a problem that should not be solved this way. Rather, [group your inventory by function](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#example-group-by-function), and either assign some variable to each group defining what the correct `raw` command should be or run multiple plays (that can live in the same playbook) each targeted at a specific function.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε my problem is regarding standard practice in infrastructure management. Each app runs on its own host as specified in the `my.hosts` file. I wish to find if the app process `ps -ef | grep <app-name>` is running on its own host(desired) and not on all `inventory-hosts`.

Comment: Then you should run all the `ps -ef` on all hosts, and have an `assert`to see if the correct process is running. The condition fro the `assert` would come from a group variable because you sorted the hosts by functions. So basically, the answer is the same: make yourself a proper inventory and your issue won't be one anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments the proper approach would be to [group the inventory by function](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#example-group-by-function) ...

---

Given an inventory of

```ini
[app1_test]
test1.example.com

[app2_test]
test2.example.com
```

a small test playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: app1_test,app2_test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    APPNAME: "app1,app2"

  tasks:

  - name: Check on
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }} on {{ group_names }}"
    when: group_names is search(item)
    with_items: "{{ APPNAME.split(',') }}"
```

is resulting into the requested output of

```
TASK [Check on] *************************
ok: [test1.example.com] => (item=app1) =>
  msg: app1 on [u'app1_test']
ok: [test2.example.com] => (item=app2) =>
  msg: app2 on [u'app2_test']
```

> *How do I put a when condition so that ... the respective app should run on the respective host only*

This means, you need to check (only) if the "app" is contained within the respective  group name(s). One host can belong to multiple groups.

**Further Q&A**

- [How do you search for substring in Ansible `group_names`?](https://serverfault.com/questions/868245/)
- [Run task only if host does not belong to a group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008083/)

**Documentation**

- [Information about Ansible: magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables)

  > *The most commonly used magic variables are `hostvars`, `groups`, `group_names`, and `inventory_hostname`.*
- [Conditionals based on `ansible_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts)