# How do I copy file based on 'group_names' in inventory file in ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have below structure in inventory file

```ini
[master_server]
192.168.10.10
[backup_server]
192.168.10.11
192.168.10.12
192.168.10.13
```

I want to copy `master.sh` to 192.168.10.10 and `backup.sh` to all servers from `backup_server` group.

How do I achieve this in an Ansible playbook?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you like to execute a task for a server only if a server belongs to certain group of hosts in your inventory file.

> *How do I achieve this in Ansible playbook?*

By using

- [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts)
- [Special Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html)
- [Playbook Conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html)
- [Conditionals based on `ansible_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts)

In example like in

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: true
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:

  - name: Copy file to target group nodes
    copy:
      src: master.sh
      dest: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}"
    register: result
    when: "'master_server' in group_names

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      var: result
```

**Similar Q&A**

- [Can I run on specific host or group of hosts in a Ansible task?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67831452/6771046)
- [Ansible - How to run tasks on specific host only and not on all `inventory_hosts`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73183244/6771046)
- [Ansible `service_facts` filtering by partial name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71420765/6771046)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to name the files you want to copy by the name of the host group `master_server.sh` and `backup_server.sh`:

```yaml
  - name: Copy file to target group nodes
    copy:
      src: "{{ group_names[0] }}.sh"
      dest: "/tmp/"
```

This will determine the group name of the host the task is running on and copies the equivalent file.

Answer (score 0):

Create the name of the file according to the name of the group. For example,

```yaml
my_file: "{{ group_names.0.split('_')|first }}.sh"
```

This will work only if the first group of a host is either `master_*` or `backup_*`.

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    my_file: "{{ group_names.0.split('_')|first }}.sh"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Copy {{ my_file }} to {{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: Copy master.sh to 192.168.10.10
  msg: Copy backup.sh to 192.168.10.11
  msg: Copy backup.sh to 192.168.10.12
  msg: Copy backup.sh to 192.168.10.13
```