# Extracting group_name From hosts

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

When I run my Ansible playbook, I define my hosts which looks to a group in my inventory.

`$ ansible-playbook -i inv/hosts conf.yml`

conf.yml:

```yaml
- name: Configure QA Nodes
  hosts: conf_qa
```

inv/hosts:

```yaml
[conf_qa]
confqa1
# confqa2

[conf_prod]
prod1
# prod2
prod3
```

Is there a way in my Roles (or other elements of the Playbook) where I can back out which `group_name` (or equivalent) is being used?

I know I could set a variable in `group_vars/conf_qa.yml` such as `qa: true` and then reference it later in my Roles

roles/init/tasks/main.yml:

```yaml
- name: Do this when dealing with the conf_qa group
  when: qa == true
```

But using `group_vars/conf_qa.yml` seems like an extra intermediary step when I was hoping to reference the host groups more directly. Is there a better way?

Comment: _I was hoping to reference the host groups_ > you can get the group of hosts a machine is in via [`group_names`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html), but mind that, since a host can be part of multiple groups, it will all depends on your settings

Comment: Aha! I didn't know you could access group_names directly. I thought I had to go through the hostvars first (e.g. hostvars.confqa1.group_names). Not a bad solution. Is there another out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following condition, this is from a playbook I created and I can confirm that it works.
It only runs the task in the servers that belong to that group, the rest of them will appear as "skipped"

```
- name: create api folder
  file:
    path: /var/log/api
    state: directory
  when: inventory_hostname in groups['switch']
```

Comment: Perfect! So for my case I use `when: inventory_hostname in groups['conf_qa']`. Thank you to both @iker lasaga and @β.εηοιτ.βε for your contributions!

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by @iker lasaga](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74101060/11875522) is definitely correct. As with most coding questions, there are multiple correct answers :D

Ansible includes `group_names`, which is a magical list containing all of the groups that the host is a part of. You can then query the list to see if your target group is in that list:

```
- name: Configure QA folder
  import_role:
    name: configure_qa
  when: "'conf_qa' in group_names"
```

Voila, you have two options ;)

[Here's where I learned about group_names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008083/run-task-only-if-host-does-not-belong-to-a-group)